# embed holoview chart with bokeh renderer in custom templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, dashboard, holoviews

I've been trying to embed bokeh charts in custom templates following 
this release updates [here](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2018/6/13/release-0-13-0/), examples [zip](https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/examples/examples-0.13.0.zip)

Now I'm trying out holoview as well and was wondering how I can embed holoview with bokeh renderer to custom templates. 
I'm not able to give name in holowview charts to achieve this

```
{{ embed(roots.mychart) }}
```

Appreciate any help if someone has already tried this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is a Bokeh level property, available on any Bokeh model. You should be able to set:

```
plot.name = "mychart"
```

on whatever Bokeh plot is returned by Holoviews.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to bigreddot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52653102/649451) if someone wants to know how to get bokeh chart from holoview

```
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
myb = renderer.get_plot(holoviewplot).state
myb.name = 'mynewchart'
curdoc().add_root(myb)
```

And then in the template

```
{{ embed(roots.mynewchart) }}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get this working for a Holoview DynamicMap?

Comment: any suggestion with Holoview DynamicMap ?

Following is not working : 

`def get_plot(doc, x, y, df, name):
    vmap = dynspread(datashade(hv.curve(x, y)).opts(width=1200,
                                                                                                     height=600,
                                                                                                     tools=["hover"])
    myplot = renderer.get_plot(vmap, doc).state
    myplot.name = name
    #plot = bk_lyout([[hvplot.state]], sizing_mode='scale_width')
    return myplot
`